# Timespan.TotalDays - can't convert double to string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan, subtraction

I was looking for the solution in Google and here but couldn't find anything about that. I am trying to get a diffence between to dates. I wrote something like

```
TimeSpan difference = timealarm.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

where timealarm is `DateTime.Now + 3 hours`. This line seems to be fine. I am trying to use

```
MessageBox.Show(difference.TotalMinutes);
```

but then I get an error mentioned in title:

> can't convert type 'double' to 'string. Visual Studio show an error
>   here - difference.TotalMinutes.

I am new in .net and c#, I guess it's simple thing.

Comment: try:  MessageBox.Show(difference.TotalMinutes.ToString());

Comment: I pasted wrong link of course, here's the irght one - https://youtu.be/iYsdAyKBN6w?t=14m52s

Answer (score 4):

`MessageBox.Show` accepts a string. The type of `difference.TotalMinutes` is `double`. There's no implicit conversion from `double` to `string`, but you can call the `ToString` method:

```
MessageBox.Show(difference.TotalMinutes.ToString());
```

That will just use the default culture you're running in to convert the value. (So whether it uses a comma or a period as the decimal separator will depend on your system, for example.)

In general, when you get an error like this, you should check:

- Is your "source" type (`double` in this case) what you expect it to be? If not, maybe you should change what you're computing.
- Is your "target" type (`string` in this case) what you expect it to be? If not, maybe you should change what you're calling, or how you're using the value.

If the types both make sense, you then need to think about how you want to convert from the "source" type to the "target" type - and that will depend on the context.

Comment: It works but why then it works without "toString()" here then - https://youtu.be/iYsdAyKBN6w ?

Comment: @RobertSzczepański: If you mean a `Console.WriteLine` call, there's an overload of `Console.WriteLine` accepting a `double`. (But I haven't watched the whole video - if you have a specific example, please explain exactly which one. Ideally in text, but just a time within that video would help - otherwise I'd be left guessing as to what's confusing you.)

Comment: I was sure i pasted link with precised time. Anyway you answered me, that was my question, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox require a string and your value is a double 
You simply need to convert double to string like this

```
MessageBox.Show(difference.TotalMinutes.ToString());
```

Comment: I think you're thinking of Java, given the use of `Double.toString`.